# std::pow gives a wrong approximation for fractional exponents

Tags: c++, c, numerical-methods

Here is what I mean trying to do

```
 double x=1.1402
 double pow=1/3;
 std::pow(x,pow) -1;
```

result is 0 but I expect 0.4465

the equation is  `(1 + x) ^3= 1.1402`, find `x`.

Comment: Debugging tip: it would be obvious that nothing is wrong with pow() if you simply inspect the arguments being passed to pow(). You would see that the value of the second argument was zero instead of 1/3, showing that pow() is operating correctly and the problem lies in your code.

Comment: Ok I already solved it.. stupid ints

Comment: EVERYBODY has made this mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dividing 1/n always returns 0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331054/dividing-1-n-always-returns-0-0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`1/3` is done as integer arithmetic, so you're assigning 0 to `pow`. Try `pow(x, 1.0/3.0);`

Answer (score 23):

1/3 is 0. That's integer division.

Try:

```
double pow = 1.0 / 3.0;
```

For:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
 double x = 1.1402;
 double pow = 1.0/3.0;
 std::cout << std::pow(x, pow) - 1;

}
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer wins, sometimes the most complete. StackOverflow is randomizing the order of answers too, so sometimes whatever comes up on top wins. Luck of the draw.

Comment: It was more that he had already accepted my answer, and later changed it to that one. I don't hold any grudges, 13 votes is quite enough, though at the time I was maxed and the acception was my only method of getting rep. No problems though :)

Answer (score 9):

Many have stated that 1/3 = 0, but have not explained why this is so.

C and C++ will perform the operation based on the the types of the operands.  Since both operands are integers, it performs an integer division creating an integer result.  When it is forced to assign that integer result to a double variable, it converts the integer 0 to a double 0.0.

It is not necessary to make both operands double, if either one is double the compiler will convert the other to double as well before performing the operation.  1.0/3 or 1/3.0 will both return the result you expected, as will 1.0/3.0.

Answer (score 1):

your 1/3 is integer division, the result of the integer division is 0.