# Division with expected result between 1 and 0 always gives 0

Tags: objective-c, math, integer, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

When I do a division calculation with an answer that's supposed to be between 1 and 0, it always returns 0.

Try this:

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;
float c = a / b; //variable divide by variable gives 0.5 as it should
float d = 1 / 2; //number divide by number gives 0
float e = 4 / 2;
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f %f", a,b,c, d, e);
```

I get this from the console:

> 2013-01-17 14:24:17.512 MyProject[1798:c07] 1.000000 2.000000 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000

I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/1402846), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2976011/1402846), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2345902/1402846), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4197841/1402846), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8459351/1402846).

Comment: you can do 1.f/2, 1.0/2, 1/2.0000f, 1/(float)2... basically anything but 2 ints

Comment: Hey, wait a second... how come you got `0.500000` for `e` being `4 / 2`? It should have been `2.000000`.

Comment: @Pang: His pants are on fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dividing integer with integer. The result will be an integer, the remainder is omitted:

```
1 / 2 = 0     The remainder (0.5) is omitted.
```

Only after the division is done, your result is passed into your `float d` variable.

EDIT: Right, I forgot to suggest a solution: Make sure at least one of your operands is a float.

```
1.0 / 2 = 0.5
```

```
1 / 2.0 = 0.5
```

Comment: And to fix it, use at least one explicit float as an operand: `1.0 / 2;` or `1 / 2.0;`