# Why does 1 / 10 equal zero unless I use variables?

Tags: c, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I return a double from two ints being divided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)

This statement in C with gcc:

```
float result = 1 / 10;
```

Produces the result 0.

But if I define variables a and b with values 1 and 10 respectively and then do:

```
float result = a / b;
```

I get the expected answer of 0.1

What gives?

Comment: What types do the variables `a` and `b` have?

Comment: You should try `float result = 1.0 / 10.0;`

Comment: I believe that's because 1/10 it's resolved in compile-time, and because you didn't specify any decimal number the compiler thinks that the number it's integer. Try to make 1.0/10.0

Comment: I answered a question just like this today.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7571326/550514

Comment: Why not just write: `float result = 0.1;`?

Comment: @rnunes compile-time or run-time makes no difference at all, 1/10 is 0 just as `a / b` is 0 when a and b are ints with values 1 and 10. It's the types that matter not when the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 11):

When the `/` operator is applied to two integers, it's an integer division. So, the result of 1 / 10 is 0.

When the `/` operator is applied to at least one float variable, it's a float division. The result will be 0.1 as you intend.

Example :

```
printf("%f\n", 1.0f / 10); /* output : 0.1 (the 'f' means that 1.0 is a float, not a double)*/
printf("%d\n", 1 / 10); /* output : 0 */
```

Example with variables :

```
int a = 1, b = 10;

printf("%f\n", (float)a / b); /* output : 0.1 */
```

Comment: To expand on this: float result = 1 / 10.0 would give the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

That happens because `1` and `10` are integer constants, so the division is done using integer arithmetic.

If at least one of your variables `a` and `b` is a `float`, it will be done using floating-point arithmetic.

If you want to do it with number literals, use the notation to make at least one of them a `float` literal, for example:

```
float result = 1.0f / 10;
```

Or cast one of them to `float`, that would be a bit more elaborate:

```
float result = 1 / (float)10;
```

Answer (score 4):

1 and 10 are both integers and will return an integer, when you define a and b you're defining as a float.  If you use 1.0 and 10.0 it will return the correct result

Answer (score 0):

If you want float than just cast it as follow.

float result = (float)a/b;