# Dividing two integers to produce a float result

Tags: c++, precision, integer-division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I return a double from two ints being divided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)

My C++ program is truncating the output of my integer devision even when I try and place the output into a float. How can I prevent this whilst keeping those to variables (a & b) as integers?

```
user@box:~/c/precision$ cat precision.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 10, b = 3;
  float ans = (a/b);
  cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3);
  cout << (a/b) << endl;
  cout << ans << endl;
  return 0;
}

user@box:~/c/precision$ g++ -o precision precision.cpp 
user@box:~/c/precision$ ./precision 
3
3.000
```

Comment: float ans = ((float)a/b); (or static_cast to please the purists)

Comment: Yes my mistake, I did have a search around but I didn't find that post. It is a dup, my bad!

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Cast the operands to floats:

```
float ans = (float)a / (float)b;
```

Comment: Also, floats only have so much precision. Your integer division might require the "double precision" of a `double`

Comment: Strictly speaking you only need to cast one integer to float, althought this does make it extra clear.

Comment: `INT K;
 K/3;` Here `/` will called for `INT` class, then what is the reason behind the that cast one int even nominator or denominator will work?

Comment: Since we are using C++ here, use `static_cast`. Note that it's possible to use the type division rule and do it simply like `float ans = static_cast<float>(a)/b;`

Comment: Absolute MAD LAD! Thank you upvoted.

Comment: what if the integer is larger than `Float.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @Maarten Then cast it to `double` or `long double`

Comment: Coming back to my comment, Float max (~2^128) > Int max (~2^31), only a lot less precise ;)

Comment: how to specify the precision? e.g I would like to have only two digits after the decimal.