# float doesn't work right

Tags: floating-point

I don't know the reason why the float doesn't print exact value when I execute this program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int a, b;
float x;

cout << "Input the value for a: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Input the value for b: ";
cin >> b;

x = - b / a;

printf("The value of x is: %.2f",x);
//cout << "The value of x is: " << x;
```

}

I want to at least when I input 2 for a and 10 for b the result should be 0.20, 
the program shows 0.00 only

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your operands as floats.

```
    ex: x = (float)a / (float)b
```

Look here for more information:

[Dividing two integers to produce a float result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447325/dividing-two-integers-to-produce-a-float-result)

Comment: doesn't `\\` gives quotient. so result will still be 5

Comment: so i cant get float answers like 1.5 if my operands are integers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all output you are expecting I think is wrong.

It should be `-5.00` -10/2 = -5. and with `%.2f` => `-5.00`

Suppose. if `a`=10 and `b`= 2, then as per your code

```
 `x= - 2/10`
```

This should give

```
 x = 0. Notice the `\`.
```

Since you are printing it with `%.2f` it gives `0.00` which the system gives.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: yes thats the result but what i want to see is the excact answer like 0.20 is there anything should i add to print out the excact value?

Comment: you can get it with @King Arthur's answer by typecasting to float