# Trying to return as double, getting integer in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a really simple calculation in C++

```
double area()
{
    return (base*height)/2;
}
```

where `base` and `height` are type `int` - though when I supply `base` and `height` values of `5` and `5` (they are declared earlier in the file) - I get back `12`, when I should be getting back `12.5` considering the `double` return type.

Am I using the return correctly, or should I be trying to use `setprecision()` or trying to cast before returning?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)

Comment: What you do with a result after it's computed has no effect on how that result is computed. That you return the result of the division as a double has no effect on how it's computed. C++'s syntax is complex enough without adding lots more complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Because `base`, `height` and `2` are all `int`, the `(base*height)/2` 's result will be an `int` too (`12` here), which will be casted to `double` when return (`12.0` here).

Change

```
return (base*height)/2;
```

to

```
return (base*height)/2.0;
```

The `(base*height)/2.0` 's result is `double` because `2.0` is double, and you could get `12.5` now.

Or as @Ajay pointed, cast `base` or `height` to `double` to avoid potential integer overflow. Such as,

```
return (static_cast<double>(base)*height)/2;
```

Comment: It may give wrong result if 'base' and 'height' are too large to be handled by integer (which may be 1 - 8 bytes). For eg. if they are `BYTE`, and are valued 250,250. It is always better to typecast one of the operand. Therefore `((double)base/height)/2` is more appropriate. 'int' is quite large, but not as large as `double`'s value capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You are perfoming an integer division here, since both arguments of the division are integers.

Casting afterwards wont help, but casting one of the arguments to a float/double will.

Easiest is to write:

```
return (base*height)/2.;
```

(The dot after the 2 makes it a double, which makes the compiler choose the floating-point division instead of integer division)

Answer (score 1):

If all the terms are int an integer division is performed and the result (an integer) is cast to a double by the return. Try using `2.0` instead, or multiply by `0.5` and avoid the division too.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
double area()
{
    return ((double)base*height)/2;
}
```

**Why?** 
Entire expression is `int` and result will be `int`.

```
double x  = 100/3;
```

Will be `33.0`  and not `33.33333` as you might expect. You need to make at least one operand to be `double`:

- 100.0/3
- 100/3.0
- double(100) / 30
- 30 / double(100)
- **NOT this:** (double)(100/3)

Answer (score 0):

**Explicit Type casting**

```
double area()
{
    return (base*height)/2.0;  //at least make any one of the operand double 

       //or   return (double(base*height))/2; external typecasting of base*height

      //or    return (double(base)*height)/2; external typecasting of base

}
```

**Simple Note:** 
when you are defining your function Then its your responsibility to return the value in the specified data type otherwise compiler will do implicit typecasting that may result in loss of precision.

For more visit this link : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson11.html