# Evaluating mathematical operations

Tags: c++

I'm running this snippet of code:

> `int x, y;
>
>       float val1, val2, val3;
>
>       x = 20;
>
>       y = 25;
>
>       val1 = x - 10;
>
>       val2 = y/val1;
>
>       val3 = float(val2);
>
>       val4 = float(y/(x-10));`

The above outputs:

> val1 = 10
>   val2 = 2.5
>   val3 = 2.5
>   val4 = 2

Can anyone explain to me why val3 and val4 evaluate differently? <del>, when in fact they're both doing the same calculations?</del>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I return a double from two ints being divided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)

Comment: "when in fact they're both doing the same calculations" - Wrong prerequisite.

Comment: Thank you @Olaf, that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are evaluated differently.

```
val3 = float(y / float(x - 10))
val4 = float(y / (x - 10)
```

For `val3`, the types are `float(int / float)` and `val4` is `float(int / int)` which will cast the result of `y / (x - 10)` to `int` first and then cast it to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

`(y/x-10)` is dealing with integers. The float isn't applied until after this calculation, which would produce `2`.

`y` and `x` are both integers. So, 20 (value of `x`) - 10 = 10. Then 25 / 10 (still dealing with integers - no floats yet) = 2.