# "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status." — how can I fix it?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double convert(int knots)
{
    double mile;
    mile = knots * 6076 / 5280 / 60;
    return mile;
}
```

I am new to C++, and I am writing a very simple function that converts knots (`int`) to miles per minute (`double`). I wrote the above function and I got the following error.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you compile it? What is the compilation command? Are you trying to build an executable?

Comment: Wasn't there any output before that line?

Comment: *"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"* is a signature for [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (GCC linker error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have another error message before that line:

> undefined reference to `main'

In order to build an executable program in C++ you need to declare the `main` function.

It is the main entry point to your program. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double convert(int knots)
{
    double mile;
    mile = double(knots) * 6076 / 5280 / 60;
    return mile;
}


int main(void) {

    double miles = convert(10); // Use convert function
    cout << "Miles: " << miles << endl; // Print result
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: You need at least one value to be explicitly cast to a `double` in order to use that `operator/` version. See *[Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)*.

And remember the associativity rules. An expression is resolved from left to right, so you only need to explicitly cast the first (or the second) operand in a multiple division/multiplication expression.

Comment: *"In order to compile in c++ you need to declare the main function."* NO! you can compile any c++ source file. There is no need in `main` to compile c++ code.