# Why does "double i = 1/12;" yields to i = 0?

Tags: c++, fractions

I think the title says everything. I want to define a variable i as the fraction 1/12. However, i is 0.

```
double i = 1/12;
std::cout << i; // Output: 0
```

Or, more specific, I want to calculate a power of something:

```
im_ = std::pow((1 + i), (1/12)) - 1;
```

However, the compile evaluates `(1/12)` as 0 and thus the result is wrong.

Comment: @Matthieu.V Nope. You should read the dupe, too.

Comment: If I define i as `float i = 1/12;` the output is also 0.

Comment: Of course. You should actually read the answers you are given, over at the duplicate.

Comment: Danke fürs Verlinken!

Answer (score 1):

Simple because `1/12` is evaluated as integer math, not floating point math.

`1/12` becomes 0 because integer math does not take into account the decimal fractions.

To get the expected result you will need to write down the numbers as a floating point literal, like this: `1.0/12.0`.

More details can be found here: [Why can't I return a double from two ints being divided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-cant-i-return-a-double-from-two-ints-being-divided)

Comment: That confuses me. I can define a double as decimal fraction such as 0.5. Then the output will be 0.5, as supposed.

Comment: @Steve: If you divide 2 integers, the compiler does an integer division, which always gives an int result.  To get a double, supply a division with at least one double in it, and the compiler will perform a floating point division.