# Why data cast is not working here in c++?

Tags: c++

```
cout <<  (float(5 / 2)) << endl;
```

It just prints `2` not `2.5` on the screen, why? 
How to do it properly?

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the result of `5 / 2`? ... and how do you imagine the cast recovers the information you seem to be seeking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-does-dividing-two-int-not-yield-the-right-value-when-assigned-to-double)

Comment: `(5 / 2)` is integer division, so the result is indeed 2, which you then cast to `float`.  You need to use actual floating-point division instead, eg: `(float(5) / 2)` or `(5.0f / 2)` or `(5 / float(2))` or `(5 / 2.0f)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: Btw, why are you using `float` type? Nowadays it's much better to use the `double` type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you aren't casting correctly, it is that you aren't doing it at the right time. Because of precedence, the `2 / 5` will be done first, with integer division, leaving `2`. This will be then be cast to a double, which stays as `2`. If you want to have it as `2.5`, you will have to cast them before you do the division. This could look like:

```
std::cout << (float)5 / (float)2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Consider instead making one of the literals a `float` directly, for example `5.f / 2`.

Comment: You only need to cast either the dividend or the divisor.