# math function for rounding off

Tags: c++, arduino

What does `(rounding/=10.0;)` mean? Why is there a slash?

Comment: Oups, it's time to start reading you beginner's C++ text book.

Comment: Do we seriously not have a duplicate for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [division assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment). It is one of the  compound assignment operators.

So if we have

```
a /= b
```

then this is exactly the same as the behavior of the expression

```
a = a / b
```

except that the expression `a` is evaluated only once and that it behaves as a single operation with respect to indeterminately-sequenced function calls.

---

So in this case

```
rounding/=10.0;
```

means

```
rounding = rounding / 10.0;
```

The reason it probably has `10.0` and not `10` is so that [integer division is avoided and floating point division is used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571326/1460794).

---

Something else to keep in mind would be that `/=` is an operator with a [lower precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `/` and that `/=` operates right-to-left while `/` operates left-to-right.

What this means in practice is that something like

```
a /= 1 / 3 / 3;
```

would be the same as

```
a /= (1 / (3 / 3));
```

which, given that `=` is also at the same level of precedence as `/=`, is the same as

```
a = (a / (1 / (3 / 3)));
```

Answer (score 6):

`rounding /= 10.0;` means:

1. convert `rounding` to `double` (if it is not `double` or `long double` already),
2. divide it by `double` 10.0,
3. and assign the quotient back to `rounding`. If `rounding` is an integer that truncates the fractional part of the quotient.

---

If `rounding` is a user-defined type with an overloaded `operator/=` that could mean anything else.

Comment: 1. Or if `rounding` is not a primitive type without an appropriate conversion operator.