# What is the operations order of these two functions

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, integer-arithmetic

I was writing a function to calculate the volume of a sphere when I encounter a problem and I don't know why if I change 4/3 * PI to PI * 4/3 I got different result.
What is the order of evaluation, if I use parenthesis like (4/3) * PI and PI * (4/3) I got the wrong answer in both cases.

```
#define PI 3.141592

float Volume(int radius){
      return (4/3 * PI * pow(radius, 3));
}

float Volume(int radius){
      return (PI * 4/3 * pow(radius, 3)); //the good one
}
```

Comment: When you divide two integers you get an integer with the truncated quotient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-does-dividing-two-int-not-yield-the-right-value-when-assigned-to-double

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (5.6 Multiplicative operators)

> 1 The multiplicative operators *, /, and % group left-to-right.

Thus this expression

```
4/3 * PI
```

is evaluated like

```
( 4/3 ) * PI
```

So in this sub-expression `4 / 3` there is used the integer arithmetic and result is equal to `1`.

This expression

```
PI * 4/3
```

also is evaluated from left to right like

```
( PI * 4 )/3
```

but in this case there is used the float arithmetic. The operand `4` is converted to the type of the variable `PI` that has the type double due to the usual arithmetic conversions. Then in turn the operand `3` is also converted to the type double because its left operand (expression) `( PI * 4 )`has the type double.

In this expression

```
PI * (4/3)
```

again inside the parentheses there is used the integer arithmetic and the result of the sub-expression is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the correct result, force the answer to be floating point like such:

```
return 4.0/3 * PI * pow(radius, 3);
```

Also, the `*` and `/` operators have the same precedence, so the expression will evaluate from left to right. So putting parentheses around `4/3` was right, except it does integer division.

Comment: It is better to use to use floating point literals across the board if that's what you want: `return (4.0/3. * PI * pow(radius, 3.));`. Most modern compilers will figure it out but it's more sensible and clearer not to rely on it.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard that before. I've mostly seen people make the first number floating point, so that the whole expression will be.