# How does one make a floating point number stop rounding to an integer?

Tags: c, floating-point, cs50

I'm trying to write a basic programme, which gets a user's input, divides by seven, and then returns the result.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s = get_int("Input:  ");
    float f = (s / 7);
    printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

Eg. if I input "8", I would expect 1.142857. But I instead simply get "1.000000". Why is this?

Comment: Look up "integer division" in C - basically, if you divide an integer, the result will also be an integer (floored). You'll want to cast `s` to a float first before dividing, e.g. `float f = (float)s / 7;`

Comment: Or just `float f = (s / 7.0);` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-does-dividing-two-int-not-yield-the-right-value-when-assigned-to-double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int s=4;
    float f = ((float)s / 7);
    printf("%f\n", f);
    getch();
}
```

You just have to typecast the int to float.  int/float division give you the floor of given integer whereas float/float division gives you float