# Sum series using function and loop (C++)

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop, sum

I am writing some code that prints out a sum series using a loop and a function.
I intend the equation to look like this

m(i) = (1/2) + (2/3) + ... (i / i + 1)

The problem is that my code always gives me incorrect answers and not printing what it's supposed to. For example, when I input 1 into 1 the answer should be 0.5

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumSeries(int x);

int main() {

    sumSeries(1);

   return 0;
}


void sumSeries(int x){

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

    sum = (x/x + 1);

    sum += sum;

    }

    cout<<sum;

}
```

Comment: Several issues. `x/x + 1` always equal 2. Integer division -> `1/2 = 0`. `sum += sum;` means you only keep the last term calculated ...

Comment: 1) `x` is an integer value. `(x/x + 1)` is also an integer value (always 2).
You need to calculate with floating point values when you want to have floating point results (e.g. `sum = (double(x)/(x + 1));`). 2) you are overwritting your sum variable in the loop with every iteration.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `x/(x+1)`?

Comment: After fixing above mentioned issues, your function will behave in an unintended way for `sumSeries(-1)`. Either use `unsigned` or handle negative input properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

```
void sumSeries(int x){

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){                 // include i in the list
        sum += static_cast<double>(i)/(i + 1);   // force the operation as double
    }
    cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: there is a mix between i and x inside the loop, problem will appear with higher values than 1

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code.

First: `(x/x+1) != (x/(x+1))`, in this case C++ obeys the normal point before line calculation rules.

Second: You are overwriting your sum in each iteration, instead of that you should direct add to sum: `sum+=x/(x+1)`

And a third issue, as noted by Simon Kraemer, is that you are using integer division, to get the correct results you must cast at least one of the operands to a floating point number.

Comment: Also `(x/(x+1))` is an integer division. It will always result in `0` as long as `x` is an integer

Comment: You are right, I have not recognised, that there is integer arithmetic in the calculation. I refered to the evaluation order.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you overwrite your sum but also take care of your integer division.
You may change it as `sum += i/(double)(i + 1);`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumSeries(int x);

int main() {

    sumSeries(5);

   return 0;
}


void sumSeries(int x){
    if (x<0)
    {
        return;
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

        sum += i/(double)(i + 1);

    }

    cout<<sum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your mathematical expression has something not normal. Do you mean M(i)= sum(1-i){i/i+1}? , or 1/2 and 1/3 are constants?

in your case as **gerum** answered it is a small Operator Precedence problem to learn how the C++ compiler prioritize the operators follow [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

your function also should have a guard against zero denominator (undefined values).

Also you should observe that you take int/int division which will ignore the remaining value. then you should consider that by converting the numerator or the denominator to double before the division [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-does-dividing-two-int-not-yield-the-right-value-when-assigned-to-double) .

then your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumSeries(int x);

int main() {

    sumSeries(1);

   return 0;
}


void sumSeries(int x){

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

      if ((x+1)!=0){
        sum += (double)x/(x + 1);
      }
      // the else will apply only if x==-1
      else {
         cout<<"the denominator is zero"<<endl;
         throw;
      }

    }

    cout<<sum;

}
```

Comment: this code produces `x * x / (x + 1)` which I don't think is what the OP wanted

Comment: thanks for commenting, I don't see any multiplication operation in my answer?! only used += .

Comment: `x/(x + 1)` added to itself `x` times is `x*x/(x+1)`, if that is the required result it'd be simpler and quicker just to do that calculation

Comment: now I understand your first comment, you are right, I mentioned that at the beginning, the mathematical notation written is ambiguous.