# How does data type assignment works?

Tags: c++

pardon if it's a beginner question. I am wondering how is the data type assignment works? Such as if I have these lines:

```
double d0 = 4 / 3;
double d1 = 4.0 / 3;
double d2 = 4 / 3.0;
```

Then, we would get `d0=1`, `d1=1.33333`, `d2=1.33333`.

My questions are:

1. Why is `d0` value is an integer of 1 instead of a decimal? Since we have assigned the data type `double` in the beginning.
2. I understand that `d1` and `d2` would be 1.33333 since it has '4.0' or '3.0' in the division, hence the compiler understands that it's not an integer. But why is it sufficient to just have one? Why shouldn't we write it as '4.0/3.0' ?
3. What would be the rules to determine these conversions?

Thank you very much beforehand

Comment: `4 / 3` is an integer division, and the result is an integer. Initializing (not assigning) a `double` variable with an integer value will not add the already missing decimals.

Comment: `d0` is not an integer -- it's a `double` that was initialized from an integer.

Comment: You just follow basic precedence.  You wouldn't assign 4 to d0 before dividing it.  You divide first.  And you can't divide a float by an integer, so why would you do the less precise one?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you assign the result of a calculation to. The calculation is going to be done with the types of the operands of the expression and the result of *that* is then going to be assigned to your final variable.

Comment: The rules are here: [Usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/usual_arithmetic_conversions)

Comment: `4` is an `int`. `4.0f` is a `float` and `4.0` is a `double`. When you mix and match types one of them is promoted to the floating point type

Comment: @paddy thanks I was just about to look that up ;) 
One of the real mistakes in C++, implicit type conversions.

Comment: See dupes [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators) and [Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571326/why-does-dividing-two-int-not-yield-the-right-value-when-assigned-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand how initialization and assignment works.

The definition

```
double d0 = 4 / 3;
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
double d0;
d0 = 4;
d0 = d0 / 3;
```

Instead it's more equivalent to

```
double d0;
int temp;
temp = 4 / 3;
d0 = temp;
```

From this it's also much easier to see why the decimals are missing, as they were never there in the first place.

---

Also note that

```
double d0 = 4 / 3;
```

is *initialization* of `d0`. It's not assignment.

While there's no real difference in this case, when using a `double` type, there's a big difference when you come to classes.