# calculation in C program always results in 0 whenever using division

Tags: c, math

I'm using two different variable to divide in the calculation with the variable from `int` and `double`. These work fine when I use something like:

```
int cost
cost = 40;
cost = (cost / 400) * 20 * 2;
```

For this the method works fine and I get the right result which is `4`, but when I use the variable `cost` and put it in the header instead, like:

```
#define cost 40
int total_cost;
total_cost = (cost / 400) * 20 * 2;
```

this always results in `0` for me and I don't know why. Even if I use `printf` with `%d` or `%f` this still gives me a result of `0`.

Comment: If you use that exact formula, with ints, i'm pretty sure it *won't* "work fine".  The problem is that the integer division gives you 0, which will happen regardless of the final type.  `cost` (or perhaps the 400) should be a `double`, or the formula simplified or operations rearranged.  For example, `(cost / 400) * 20 * 2` == `(cost / 400) * 40` == `cost * 40 / 400` == `cost / 10`, unless you *intend* to rely on integer division.  (Doesn't seem to be the case, considering how much trouble it's giving you.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing integer division - which rounds down.

Therefore:

```
cost / 400
```

is returning zero because `cost = 40` and `40 / 400` rounds down to zero.

What you should do is use a floating-point type like `double`.

EDIT:

```
double cost
cost = 40;
cost = (cost / 400) * 20 * 2;
```

and

```
#define cost 40
double total_cost;
total_cost = ((double)cost / 400) * 20 * 2;
```

Comment: what will be the the solution since my assignment needed to put the value in header only

Comment: Declare your variables as type `double`. So `double cost` and `double total_cost`. Furthermore, you need to cast your values to `double` before the division.

Comment: Or alternatively just cast them to double in the computation to enforce floating point operations: `((double)cost / 400.0) * 20.0 * 2.0`.

Comment: @Ali The define would just be `#define cost 40.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations, and Integer Division.

Integer Division always truncates.  Mathematically, 40/400 = .1 - but that's not an integer.  The remainder is thrown away, leaving you with:  `40 / 400 = 0`.

Order of operations means that the division is done first, in your example.  Since the order of multiplication and division doesn't matter too much (mathematically speaking), try changing the order:

```
total_cost = cost * 20 * 2 / 400;
```

Multiplication happens first, division last, giving you:

```
40 * 20 * 2 / 400 = 800 * 2 / 400 = 1600 / 400 = 4
```