# Why can't my float variable store numbers after the decimal point?

Tags: c, variables, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c=2,n=5;
    float percent;
    percent=(c/n)*100;
    printf("%.3f\n",percent);
}
```

what's wrong in this code please..?

Comment: so many duplicates: [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2345902/995714), [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/995714), [calculation in C program always results in 0 whenever using division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7720078/995714)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       percent=(c/n)*100;

       2/5    ---> 0 because it is integer division 
       0*100  ---> 0
```

It is an integer division, So you can change this to

```
       percent=((float)c/n)*100;

       2/5     ----> 0.4
       0.4*100 ----> 40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division. It always truncates the value. Make sure you cast either one first then it will use floating point division.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c=2,n=5;
    float percent;
    percent=((float)c/n)*100;
    printf("%.3f\n",percent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Division operation between integers yield another integer. Since c, n & 100 are integers you get an integer as a result with .0 since the type is declared as float. The other answers here should produce your desired answer.