# Objective C datatypes/Math returning 0.0000

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C problem - division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/c-problem-division-result-is-always-zero)

I'm trying to get my head around how objective C works, Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
double hr = ((1/360) * 300);
NSLog(@"%f", hr);
```

returns:

```
2012-06-06 14:07:02.511 Clock2[3385:f803] 0.000000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and related languages such as C++ and Objective C use integer (truncating) division when both LHS and RHS are integers, so 1 / 360 = 0. For floating point arithmetic try to get into the habit of using floating point literals, even for whole numbers, i.e. change:

```
double hr = ((1/360) * 300);
```

to:

```
double hr = ((1.0/360.0) * 300.0);
```

Comment: Thanks :D doubt I would have got that on my own

Comment: Probably a good idea to read a decent C book for the basics such as this, since Objective C is built on top of C, and you need to have a good understanding of the foundations.

Comment: And if you were really going old school and were concerned about float implementation issues (which are probably irrelevant nowadays), you'd structure it as (1.0 * 300.0)/360.0