# Division in c not giving expected value

Tags: c, double, division

When doing a division im getting a rounded answer?

```
double div;
div = 25/8;
printf("%lf",div);
```

When i do this prints out `3.0000`

why dont i get `3.125`?

Comment: Check arithmetic conversion rules for C http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [C problem - division result is always zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/c-problem-division-result-is-always-zero)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are doing an integer division, try with:

```
div = 25.0/8;
```

or

```
div = (double)25/8;
```

Typing `25.0` means a double literal. You could also use `25.f` for a float literal. Both of these trigger floating point division.

Comment: what about in the situation i have an array and i want to divide it by the size of the arrays for example like ---------

div  = (sizeof(fulltext) / sizeof(fulltext[0])) / 8;

Comment: sizeof returns an unsigned int so you'll get integer division. If you really want a double out of it, you can cast the return.

Comment: An array is always a whole multiple of its element size

Comment: Well there's a '/8' at the end so it might get to a floating point value.

Answer (score 1):

Typecast it, i.e. change it to:

```
double div;
div = (double)25/(double)8;
printf("%lf",div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both the numerator and denominator are integer values, division operator performs only integer division and skips fractional part for optimization purpose.

So you need to specify by typecasting or making 25 as 25.0 or 8 as 8.0 that you want fractional part as well.

Answer (score 1):

Either typecast explicitly to double data type or change numerator to get desired value i.e. 25.o or use floating point literal 25.f.