# An unexpected result about divide in C

Tags: c, division

My goal is to output the average of the input number and its reversal.

When I input 974, the result is 726.0 instead of 726.5. I have think about this problem for long time but I still cannot get the answer.

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int N, D1, D2, D3;
    double aver;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    D1 = N % 10;
    D2 = ((N - D1) / 10) % 10;
    D3 = (N - D1 - D2) / 100;
    aver = (D1*100 + D2*10 + D3 + N) / 2;

    printf("%lf", aver);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `int` divided by an `int` is an `int`. `(D1*100 + D2*10 + D3 + N)` is an `int`. If you want `double` division, divide it by `2.0` instead of `2`.

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `N`, `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, all are `int`s, so the calculation

```
(D1*100 + D2*10 + D3 + N) / 2;
```

is performed as integer arithmetic and later the result is being promoted to `double`. So, the result is just a `double` representation of an `int` value.

To enforce a floating point arithmatic, either

1. Change the operand data type(s) to `double` or `float`.
2. Cast at least one operand to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `double`. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int N, D1, D2, D3;
    double aver;

scanf("%d", &N);
D1 = N % 10;
D2 = ((N - D1) / 10) % 10;
D3 = (N - D1 - D2) / 100;
aver = (double)(D1*100 + D2*10 + D3 + N) / 2;

printf("%lf", aver);

return 0;
}
```

Checkout the **[Running code](http://ideone.com/LURvfG)**