# Why does the c variable always output 0?

Tags: c, floating-point, int

I am trying to write a program to convert fahrenheit to celsius.
No matter what you input, `c` always outputs `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int f;
float c;

printf("Enter a temperature in fahrenheit: ");
scanf("%d", &f);

c = (f-32)*(5/9);

printf("%d fahrenheit is %.2f celsius.\n", f, c);
}
```

Comment: `(5/9)` is an integer calculation, result = 0. Try `(f-32)*5/9;`.

Comment: `f` is an int as well as `32`, `5` and `9`. You need explicit casting, that is `c = (f-32) * ((float)5/9)` or `c = (f-32) * (5.0/9)` (yea! `5.0` it's not the same as `5`!)

Comment: Being used to standard measurement units: Do Farhenheit temperatures have no fraction? Why use an integer for Fahrenheit, but a `float` for Celsius?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In integer math, 5/9 is 0, remainder 5. You want 5.0/9.0 instead.

In C, what you do with a result has no effect on how it's computed. So even though `c` is a float and you are storing the result of the math in a `float`, the math is still integer math because `5`, `9`, `f` and `32` are all integers.