# Exception in HDR tutorial

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm doing a tutorial on creating HDR images and when I call the process function of the `calDebevec` or `mergeDebevec` I keep getting this exception:

[image: Exception]

I tried using following library versions: 2.4.13.2, 3.1 and 3.2 with no success.

Code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
vector<Mat> images;
vector<float> exposures;

exposures.push_back(1 / 180);
exposures.push_back(1 / 750);
exposures.push_back(1 / 45);

String path = "/path/to/pictures";

Mat buffer = imread(path + "grandcanal_mean.jpg"); 
images.push_back(buffer);
buffer = imread(path + "grandcanal_under.jpg");
images.push_back(buffer);
buffer = imread(path + "grandcanal_over.jpg");
images.push_back(buffer);

//Ptr<MergeDebevec> mergeDebevec = createMergeDebevec();

Mat l;

Ptr<CalibrateDebevec> calDebevec = createCalibrateDebevec();
calDebevec->process(images, l, exposures);

//mergeDebevec->process(images, l, exposures);
return 1;
}
```

The link to the tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d3/db7/tutorial_hdr_imaging.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division result is always zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using the debug dll instead of the release version.

Answer (score 0):

You have an integer division: `1 / 45` is `0.0f`. Notice that tutorial manages to dodge the bullet by supplying `float` as divider.

Comment: I tried using float numbers by dividing the exposure times and that didn't change it. So instead of using division i used the following floats:

0.0055f
0.0013f and
0.02f

Comment: @Rok because you have used the wrong way. You must use `1.0f/45` or `1/45.0f` or `1.0f/45.0f` [Division result is always zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2345902/995714)