# i cant find geometric average in c

Tags: c, math, average

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

 int array[5];
 int x;
 int max;
 int y;
 float k;

 printf("Enter capacity of array")
 scanf("%d",&y);

 for(x=0;x<y;x++)
    {
     printf("Enter the numbers:");  
     scanf("%d",&array[x]);
     max*=array[x]; 
    }

  k=pow(max,(1/y) );

  printf("%d\n",max); 
  printf(" %f",k);

 getch();
 }
```

Hello everyone, I want find geometric average but I always get k=1
 I know it's simple code but I can't see the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: In `max*=array[x];` the variable `max` was *uninitialised* so the result will be indeterminate. It should be `int max = 1;` apart from any algorithm problem.

Comment: Read up on integer division in C.

Comment: learn to use your platform / toolchains debugger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Answer (score 1):

With `int y`, the expression `1/y` is equal to 0 in most cases...

More precisely, in all cases, except for when `y` is -1 or 0 or +1.

So you might want to start by changing it to `1.0/y`...

Comment: P.S.: the variable `max` is not even initialized in your code, so I guess you've got a whole bunch of other problems there...

Answer (score -1):

check this out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double array[5];
    int max = 1, y;
    printf("Enter Capacity of Array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for (int i = 0;i < y;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the %d Number:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &array[i]);
        max *= array[i];
    }
    printf("Multiplication Of Array = %d\n\n", max);
    printf("Geomteric Mean = %0.2lf\n", pow(max, (1.0/y)));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: That array[5] is going to be a big problem....

Comment: how? can you explain it

Comment: What if they want to enter 6 items?  You've overflowed the array.

Comment: i just have given example how he can do it..that's all.He is doing programming then he should know if he will enter more than 5 numbers it will show garbage output.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int x;
int max = 1;
int y;
float k;

printf("Enter capacity of array");
scanf("%d",&y);
int array[y];

for(x=0;x<y;x++)
    {
    printf("Enter the %d number:",x+1);  
    scanf("%d",&array[x]);
    max*=array[x]; 
    }

k=pow(max,(1.0/y) );

printf("%d\n",max); 
printf("%f",k);
getch();

}
```

Hope this will help