# "warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]" when not dividing by zero

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

My code for the following simple coding exercise produces a "division by zero" warning, and I'm wondering why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("celsius=%d fahrenheit=%d\n", i, (i/(5/9))+32);
  }

  return 1;

}
```

```
temps.c: In function ‘main’:
temps.c:6:45: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
     printf("celsius=%d fahrenheit=%d\n", i, (i/(5/9))+32);
```

Answer (score 1):

I realised while writing this question that it's because I should have written `5.0/9.0`, since C handles division with integers in [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero) that I didn't expect. Posting this anyway since I couldn't find this particular error linked to this particular problem on SO.