# Simple division of 2/12 with double causing errors

Tags: c, division

I don't know what is causing this error, I try dividing 2/12 using double but it gives me a completely wrong number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double a;
    a = 2/12;
    printf("\n a = %lf  \n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This returns -272632568  and makes no sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What compiler and flags?

Comment: I'm using Xcode and I've tried with other compilers, including online ones, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `%d` is for integers, use `%f`. Your compiler could've warned you about this, consider enabling the warnings. Also note that `2/12` does integral division and truncates the result, add `.` to at least one of the operands to fix that: `2/12.0`.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, spotted by MSVC: **warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double'**

Comment: But even correcting the format to `%f`, remember that `2 / 12` is performed as **integer division** (giving zero) - only afterwards is it converted to a double.

Comment: Anyone want to guess what the next question the OP asks is going to be, if they show the same willingness to do research first as for this question?

Comment: My compiler prints the correct answer (which is 0, not 0.166666... as you would expect, because you are doing integer division). Is this the exact code you compiled when computing that non-sense answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Comment: @phuclv That still doesn't explain the result that the OP got (-272632568)

Comment: The format specifier `%lf` is unspecified and gives undefined behavior (the `l` modifier can only be applied to int formats).  Some libraries may treat it as `long double`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd `%lf` means `double` argument. For `long double` use `%Lf`. This is standard, not a compiler extension. Who told you that the `l` modifier can only be applied to `int` formats? It can be applied even to chars or strings to make them wide.

Comment: @DarkAtom: The spec told me -- `%f` means a `double` argument, `%Lf` means `long double`.  `%lf` is unspecified, so undefined behavior.  Wide chars/strings is a recent extension, not part of the original C89 spec.

Comment: I was talking about the C99 standard and later. In no way is the question marked C89 specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should consider the declaration:

```
double a = 2 / 12; // (integer)
```

It'll just give you zero and then assign to double since they're integers. If you use rather:

```
double a = 2.0 / 12.0; // explicitly defining
```

Then you'll get right precision output by using this statement:

```
printf("\n a = %f\n", a);
```

Or,

```
printf("\n a = %lf\n", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `%d` in your format string, however `%d` means integer not double.

You want to use `%f` inplace of `%d`

See here for details: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions

Comment: I saw that mistake after posting the question and now edited it, it still gives mistakes but thanks for the observation