# Dividing 1/n always returns 0.0

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, floating-point-conversion

I am trying to calculate `p1=(1/1)*(1/2)*...*(1/n)` but something is wrong and the `printf` gives me `0.000...0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i,num;
    float p3;

    do {
        printf ("give number N>3 : \n" );
        scanf( "%d", &num );
    } while( num <= 3 );

    i = 1;
    p3 = 1;  

    do {
        p3=p3*(1/i);
        printf( "%f\n",p3 );
    } while ( i <= num );

    printf("\nP3=%f",p3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The division in `p3*(1/i)` is integer division. Try `p3 * (1.0 / i)` instead. Oh ... and use `double` rather than `float` for your floating-point numbers.

Comment: Isn't the second loop infinite? It waits for a condition to be met on `i` and `num`, yet it does not alter either one of them.

Comment: sorry i didnt copy the entire code

Comment: What about doing `p3 /= i;` instead? ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(1/i)
```

`i` is an `int`, so that's integer division, resulting in 0 if `i > 1`. Use `1.0/i` to get floating point division.

Answer (score 6):

`1` is an integer, `i` is an integer. So `1/i` will be an integer, *ie* the result will be truncated. To perform floating-point division, one of the operands shall be of type `float` (or, better, of type `double`):

```
p3 *= 1. / i;
```

Comment: and why double instead of float?

Comment: @user1809300 it has more precision.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The basic case:

- when you want to get float output from two integers, you need to convert one into float

  `int c = 15;
   int b = 8;
   printf("result is float %f\n", c / (float) b); // result is float 1.875000
   printf("result is float %f\n", (float) c /  b); // result is float 1.875000`