# how to divided like normal math?

Tags: c++

/////////////////////////////////
    // Start of your code

```
// Ask the user to enter the price per quantity and the amount
// she would like to purchase
cout<< "Grocerry price calculator" <<endl;

cout<< "what is the price given $";
cin>> price;

cout<<"For how many Items? ";
cin >> quantity;

cout<< "How many would you like to purchase";
cin>> amount;






// Calculate the cost for the amount the user would like to purchase

cost =( amount / quantity) * price;


cout << amount <<" of the product cost ";
cout << cost <<endl;
```

I need to do something like this price =2, quantity =7, amount = 12. 12/7= 1.71428571, 1.714*2 = 3.42857143

but i get 2 as my answer instead of 3.42857143 and i dont know to keep the decimal. and then i have to round up to 3.43 which i dont know how to do it either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [divide floats with integers in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331054/divide-floats-with-integers-in-c)

Comment: If you don't want integer results, don't use integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

That's because both `amount` and `quantity` are integers, so you get integer division.
Multiply `amount` by 1.0 go make it floating point (`double` to be more precise), and get floating point arithmetics.

`cost =( 1.0 * amount / quantity) * price;`

Make sure that `cost`'s type is `double`, not `int`.

Comment: cost is type as a double

Comment: Typecast to double would also work (the operands, **not** the result.)

Comment: @user3020221, then just add multiplication by 1.0 inside the parens, as the answer suggests, it should address your problem.

Comment: Multiplying by `1.0` is an obscure way to do this. You just want a conversion, so use a cast, probably `static_cast<double>(...)`. Better yet, define your variables as `double` in the first place.