# Mathematical operation on macro value in C

Tags: c

The output of the following program is `T = 0.0000`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Fs 8000

int main()
{
    float T = 1/Fs;
    printf("T = %f", T);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, when the macro `Fs` is declared as a float variable inside main, I get the correct output `T = 0.000125`. Can anyone explain what is going on? Is it possible to get the correct output with the macro too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float Fs = 8000;
    float T = 1/Fs;
    printf("T = %f", T);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting the correct answer when you divide by a `float`. You are getting an incorrect answer when you divide by an `int`.  See [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: An int divided by an int gives you an int.  It doesn't matter if the variable on the left side of the `=` is float.  The "damage" has already been done on the right side of the `=`.

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Comment: OT: You only use `#include <math.h>` when using definitions or function prototypes from that library (like `sin()` or `atan()`). It is not needed for basic floating point operations. (PS: Use `double` instead of `float` unless there are other constraints.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does division result in zero instead of a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/why-does-division-result-in-zero-instead-of-a-decimal)

Comment: duplicate: [Dividing 1/n always returns 0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13331054/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer divided by integer = integer. Integer divided by float = float.
Either:

```
#define Fs 8000.0
```

and/or

```
float T = 1.0/Fs;
```

and/or

```
float T = 1/(float)(Fs);
```

Comment: Nitpick: `1.0` is a `double`, not a `float`. `1.0f` is clearer. Ditto for `8000.0`. Only mentioning because for more involved code, the compiler might generate a bunch of instructions to convert things from float to double and back again.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain what is going on?

In C the type used by an operator is picked based on that operator's operands and *not* based on the type where you store the result.

Also everything including constants has a type. `8000` is type `int`, `8000.0` is type `double` and `8000.0f` is type `float`.

In case of `1/Fs` with `Fs` as a macro for the integer `8000`, then both operands of the division are `int`. Therefore the division is carried out on `int` type and you get the result `0` because of it.

In case of `1/Fs` with `Fs` as type `float`, one operand of the division is `int` and the other is `float`. Something called "the usual arithmetic conversions" (see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)) then "promotes" the `int` to type `float`. The division is carried out on `float` type.

---

Some best practices:

- Avoid mixing integers/`int` constants with floating point arithmetic. Instead write every expression involving floating point with pure floating point constants/variables.
- Use `8000.0f` when dealing with `float` and `8000.0` when dealing with `double`.
- `float` is a type that should barely ever be used in C programs and never in beginner programs. The *only* scenario where you should ever use `float` is when your CPU has a single precision FPU but no hardware support for `double` precision - which is a very specific scenario and not applicable to modern x86 PC where `double` should be used everywhere.
- Avoid writing code relying on implicit type promotions. If correct types are used from the start, such promotions can be avoided.